# EOS RAM requirement for hosting a full node?

Tags: ram, dapp

https://medium.com/@bytemaster/eosio-ram-market-bancor-algorithm-b8e8d4e20c73

In this article, Dan pointed to the fact that "Keeping RAM scarce (64 GB) lowers the cost of hosting a full node, but increases the cost of interacting with the blockchain."

I understand that keeping a small amount of RAM available will push the price of RAM on EOS RAM MARKET, but how does having a limited amount of RAM in EOS Blockchain will lower the cost of hosting a full node?

I understand for Block Producers, they have to comply with the minimum requirement of RAM as suggested by the current status(https://www.eosrp.io/), so that they can be fully synced and communicate with EOS Blockchain. Does this requirement extends to regular dAPP developers? Do they have to have +90GB RAM in order to host a full-node?

Answer (score 0):

To host an EOS node It is good practice to compare your hardware specifications with the current block producers but for non-producing nodes you can do some tweaks to have your node fully synced even with less hardware specifications as well. For example:
In config.ini file you can set `validation-mode = light` and as per its documentation describes

> Chain validation mode ("full" or "light").
>    In "full" mode all incoming blocks will be fully validated.
>    In "light" mode all incoming blocks headers will be fully validated; transactions in those validated blocks will be trusted

So your node will not be fully validating the blocks hence will require less RAM and CPU to keep fully synced.

Note: I'm running my non-producing node with 32GB RAM and 3.4 GHz CPU and 1 TB SSD and its doing GREAT with mongo instance as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. What would be the main adventage of hosting a full node and a light client node?? Would dAPP developers need to host a full-node in any case?

Comment: Hosting a full node ensures you most stable, fast and decentralize solution for your dapps though it all depends upon your dapp requirements because there are third party node available and you can use their APIs in your dapp as well. So, It is recommended for dapp developers to host their own full node but not required though.

Comment: 1. Where can I find minimum hardware requirements for hosting a 'light' client node?